# Return the Number of the Last Merged Pull Request Git

Tags: git

I want to return the number of latest merged pull request. The Git command `git show --merges --count` currently achieves this (see below) however, I want to **only** return the latest merged pull request number. In my case, **#402**.

Any idea how to achieve this? It's worth mentioning that I also tried `git rev-list --count HEAD` but this only returns the total number of commits on the repository.

```
C:\Dev\home>git show --merges --count

commit 46kh4k56h4h56hk45h6k4h56k4jh56kjh45k6h
Merge: 4564hhf5 4h456hr
Author: kerbol 
Date:   Mon Feb 15 10:02:04 2019

Merge pull request #402 from FSP/JIRA-992_job_import

JIRA-992. job_import
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a `grep` on the pattern you want, then limit to just the first match:

```
git log --grep="Merge pull request #[0-9]\+" --pretty=oneline -1
    | sed -En "s/.*#([[:digit:]]\+).*/\1/p";
```

This would show the first commit matching the pattern `Merge pull request#[0-9]+`.  If you want more than one, e.g. three, then just use `-3` at the end of the above command.

**Edit:**

If you additionally want to extract the commit number from the output of `git log` above, then consider piping it into `sed`.

Comment: that didn't return anything for me when running locally on my windows machine

Comment: @Kerbol You were right, there was a mistake.  The `+` in the regex pattern for `grep` needs to be escaped.  Please try the answer again.

Comment: I just dropped that and ran accordingly. Still need to figure out how to return the latest pull request number. Actually, my mistake, it IS returning the latest pull request upon checking. What I need to do is strip away the remaining text to just show the number so that I can pass it to a variable.

Comment: Try piping the entire `git log` call into `grep`, a second time.

Comment: I get `'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command` in my Git CMD shell running on Windows so I guess I can't pipe output.

Comment: @Kerbol Didn't know that `grep` doesn't work on Git bash.  Use `sed` instead.

Comment: sed is more for Unix if I'm not mistaken. I'll have to use powershell it looks like. Any idea how to do this with powershell? Specifically the Regex part.
`$git_latest_merged_pull_request_number_raw=$(git log --grep="Merge pull request #[0-9]\+" --pretty=oneline -1)`
`$git_latest_merged_pull_request_number_extract = get-content $git_latest_merged_pull_request_number_raw | where { $_ -match "expression"}`

Comment: @Kerbol Actually, from what I have read, `sed` should actually work with the Git bash.

Comment: yeah, I am restricted with this weird legacy environment setup but I achieve with powershell as follows:
`$git_latest_merged_pull_request_number_raw=$(git log --grep="Merge pull request #[0-9]\+" --pretty=oneline -1)`
`($git_latest_merged_pull_request_number_raw -split '#')[1].substring(0,3)`